# Integrate socket.io into reactjs + redux that uses REST

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io

My project consists of a backend(nodejs , express, mysql) and a frontend (reactjs, redux).

The flow of a rendered component is in a simple redux pattern-

1. in `ComponentDidMount` I call an action creator `this.props.getResource()`
2. in action creator I use axios to call the backend and dispatch an action in callback like so :

**actions.js**

```
export const getResource = () => dispatch => {
      axios.get(API_URL/path/to/resource)
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({
            type: SOME_RESOURCE,
            payload: res.data
          });
        })
        .catch(e =>
          dispatch({
            type: ERROR,
            payload: e
          })
        );
    };
```

3. in reducer I send back to component the state with the new array :

**reducers.js**

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_RESOURCE:
      return {
        ...state,
        resources: [...state.resources, action.payload] // add new resource to existing array
      };
     }
    default: return state;
     }
   }
```

It is working as it should using REST APIs but now I wish to replace a certain API call with a socket so that data is shown in real-time without needing to refresh the page.

How can I convert above example to use sockets instead of API calls?

This is what I have tried:

1. Flow starts the same - I call an action creator in `ComponentDidMount`
2. I changed the action creator to the following :

**actions.js**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io(); // localhost backend

export const getResource= () => dispatch => {
  socket
    .on("getResourceEvent", res => {
      dispatch({
        type: SOME_RESOURCE,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .on("onError", e => {
      dispatch({
        type: ERROR,
        payload: e
      });
    });
};
```

3. no changes in **reducers.js**

This works but with each rendering of the component, the `store.getState()` gets called 1 additional time. On first render `getState()` is called 1 time and if I refresh the page I get 2 calls from `getState()` and so on.

What's causing this behavior and how can I prevent it?

**Edit:**

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [ thunk ];

var createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);

var store = createStoreWithMiddleware(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)

store.subscribe(() => console.log("Store.getState()", store.getState()))

export default store;
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something here, where in your code do you call `store.getState()`? Also you probably need to remove the registered socket events when the component unmounts?

Comment: I subscribed to the store so getState is called every time the state changes

Comment: Could you share the subscribe code? It's difficult to diagnose what's going on without seeing the whole component actually

Comment: @AndrewCraswell I edited my post with store.js

Comment: Do you have this in a codesandbox somewhere? If the component is unmounting and remounting when it performs the re-render you describe, then the issue is that un mount, you're registering events -- but when the component unmounts, you're not removing the listeners. When the component remounts, a second event is reigstered. This will trigger an additional action to be dispatched on each remount.